# CSS Animations, start and stop infinite animation on click

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

Is there any way to do that without javascript or do I have to use JS to append/remove class from an object?
Could you guys show me some live example?
Right now I have something that works only on hover of the object:

```
  .clicker:hover + .circle {
    -webkit-animation: rotor 1.5s linear 0s infinite normal;
    -mox-animation: rotor 1.5s linear 0s infinite normal;
    -o-animation: rotor 1.5s linear 0s infinite normal;
    animation: rotor 1.5s linear 0s infinite normal;
  }

  .paused{
    -webkit-animation-play-state:paused;
    -moz-animation-play-state:paused;
    -o-animation-play-state:paused; 
    animation-play-state:paused;
}
```

Comment: There is no click Action in CSS

Comment: you have to use javascript or jquery..

Comment: so could you show me how?

Comment: [ https://codepen.io/CWiech05/pen/yOpQgq?q=stop%20animation%20on%20click&limit=all&order=popularity&depth=everything&show_forks=false ] take a look at this sample, do you mean something like that?

Comment: on your click, it Stops and Starts the animation again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming this (from your CSS)...

```
<div class="clicker">[Your Content]</div>
<div class="circle">[Your Content]</div>
```

**WITH PURE JAVASCRIPT:**

```
<div class="clicker" onclick="this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('paused');">[Your Content]</div>
<div class="circle">[Your Content]</div>
```

**WITH JQUERY:**

```
$('.clicker').click(function(){
    $(this).next('.circle').toggleClass('paused');
});
```

You haven't post your html, so the JavaScript/jQuery selectors I'm using are base on your CSS. For a more specific answer with the best selectors, you should show your html.

**EDIT:**

I've just realized that with this solution you could have a problem with your CSS, because `.circle` styles prevails over `.paused`, so the class is been toggled but the styles aren't changing. You can easily solve it adjusting your CSS...

```
.clicker + .circle {
    -webkit-animation: rotor 1.5s linear 0s infinite normal;
    -mox-animation: rotor 1.5s linear 0s infinite normal;
    -o-animation: rotor 1.5s linear 0s infinite normal;
    animation: rotor 1.5s linear 0s infinite normal;
}

.paused {
    -webkit-animation-play-state: paused !important;
    -moz-animation-play-state: paused !important;
    -o-animation-play-state: paused !important; 
    animation-play-state: paused !important;
}
```

I hope it helps

Comment: Personally, I like this answer the best.

Comment: Thanks, @Manticore !!

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible in CSS, however if you are interested in a JavaScript example:

```
$(element).on('click', function () {

    if ($(target).hasClass('paused'))
    {
        $(target).removeClass('paused');
    }

    else 
    {
        $(target).addClass('paused');
    }

});
```

Replace `element` with the button or anchor that activates the class removal / addition. And replace `target` with the element that should animate.

This solution requires **jQuery**.

Comment: You may want to note, that this JS Solution requires jQuery

Comment: @MatthiasS. Just did :)

Answer (score 2):

```js
var active = document.querySelector('.active');
var div = document.querySelector('.wrap');
var hasAnimationPaused = false;
var aniamtionPausedClass = 'paused'

div.className += ' circle';
active.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  var classNames = div.className.split(' ');
  if (!hasAnimationPaused) {
    div.className += ' ' + aniamtionPausedClass;
    hasAnimationPaused = true;
  } else {
    classNames.splice(classNames.indexOf(aniamtionPausedClass), 1);

    div.className = classNames.join(' ');
    hasAnimationPaused = false;
  }
})
```

```css
.wrap {
  color: black;
}
@keyframes rotor {
from {
  color: red;
}
50% {
  color: yellow;
}
to {
  color: blue;
}
}
.circle {
    -webkit-animation: rotor 1.5s linear 0s infinite normal;
    -mox-animation: rotor 1.5s linear 0s infinite normal;
    -o-animation: rotor 1.5s linear 0s infinite normal;
    animation: rotor 1.5s linear 0s infinite normal;
  }
  .paused{
    -webkit-animation-play-state:paused;
    -moz-animation-play-state:paused;
    -o-animation-play-state:paused; 
    animation-play-state:paused;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap"> TEst Test</div>
<button class="active">CLick</button>
```