# Click the button again to stop animation after 4 seconds

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a statement if its true it clicks the button to play the animation, I want it to click the button again after 4 seconds to stop the animation. Below is the code in the if statement.

```
document.getElementById("clickButton").click();
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can see answers here : [CSS Animations, start and stop infinite animation on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46442006/css-animations-start-and-stop-infinite-animation-on-click)
And for after 4 seconds to stop the animation , You can Use [setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout) or [setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval)

Comment: Instead of just adding links to solutions. Describe the solution here and add supporting links